# Mule Batch processing Auto delete of source file not working

Tags: mule

SFTP connector does not delete the ssource file after reading in batch processing, while run as normal flow the file gets deleted

I am setting autoDelete="true" condition in the SFTP connector. Can anyone please suggest how to handle this scenario

```
<context:property-placeholder location="dev.properties"/>
<encryption:config name="Encryption" defaultEncrypter="PGP_ENCRYPTER" doc:name="Encryption">
    <encryption:pgp-encrypter-config publicKeyRingFileName="keys/dev_pgp_wd_ecc_public.key.gpg" secretKeyRingFileName="keys/dev_pgp_wd_ecc_private.key.gpg" secretAliasId="${key.AliasId}" secretPassphrase="${key.Passphrase}" principal="${key.principal}"/>
</encryption:config>

<amqp:connector name="AMQP_Connector" validateConnections="true" host="${amqp.host}" doc:name="AMQP Connector" virtualHost="${amqp.virtualhost}" password="${amqp.password}" port="${amqp.port}" username="${amqp.user}"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_PI" host="${pi.endpoint}" port="${pi.port}" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="${pi.path}" responseTimeout="30000">
    <http:basic-authentication username="${pi.username}" password="${pi.password}"/>
</http:request-config>
<smtp:connector name="SMTP_Alert" contentType="text/html" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SMTP"/>
<sftp:connector name="SFTP_Inbound_Connector" validateConnections="true" autoDelete="true" pollingFrequency="120000" doc:name="SFTP"/>

 <batch:job name="TestBatch" max-failed-records="-1">
    <batch:input>
        <sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="SFTP_Inbound_Connector" host="${sftp.host}" port="${sftp.port}" path="/test/incoming/lt" user="${sftp.user}" password="${sftp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP"/>

        <encryption:decrypt config-ref="Encryption" using="PGP_ENCRYPTER" doc:name="Encryption"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <logger message="Decrypted" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <splitter expression="#[xpath3('/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry', payload, 'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="b7cbbbbb-d58b-439b-8684-5a6d0345d48c">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="empty.xml"/>
            <dw:set-payload></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </batch:input>
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Batch_Step1">
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            <batch:commit size="5" doc:name="Batch Commit">
                <amqp:outbound-endpoint exchangeName="${amqp.exchangeName}" queueName="${amqp.queueName}" responseTimeout="10000" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/xml" connector-ref="AMQP_Connector" doc:name="AMQP"/>
            </batch:commit>
        </batch:step>

    </batch:process-records>
    <batch:on-complete>
        <logger message="#[flowVars.totalRecords.totalRecords]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger message="#[flowVars.failedReocrds.failedReocrds]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>            
        <set-payload value="${mail.html}" doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="text/html"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${mail.host}" port="${mail.port}" user="${mail.user}" password="${mail.password}" connector-ref="SMTP_Alert" to="${mail.receiver}" from="${mail.from}" subject="${IntegrationName}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
    </batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be bugs around autoDelete and SFTP:
https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-9144

So maybe this is the issue you are running into however in your normal flow you say it works.

So an option is to try a normal flow together with the batch execute component, so your FTP inbound endpoint and collection creation is part of a flow and from that flow you execute the batch processing. The input section of your batch element will be empty.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/batch-processing#triggering-batch-jobs

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am implementing the decryption logic in the flow. I have identified while testing if I remove the decryption logic the Auto delete works, but when enabled it doesn't work.

Comment: what if you put the Object to String transformer direct after SFTP and after that transformer place your decryption logic, will that work in your usecase? The thing i'm thinking of is an issue of not closing the stream, you have streaming enabled on the SFTP connector?

Comment: I have used object to byte array and it worked. Thank you for the inputs.